# react router get props in parent

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's take this basic template

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
       <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

There is no problem to access `props.match` from `About` or `Users`.

I would like to access with `Header`, using `withRouter` I have `props.match.path` always equal to `/`, I would like the path to be `/user` when I am in the `Users` component for example.

I would change my header render in function of `props.match.params` elements

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are searching for is defeind under `props.location.pathname`

example: https://github.com/zero-to-mastery/visual-music/blob/development/src/components/TopNav/TopNav.js

Comment: Not really, I could do it with `props.location.pathname` but it would be much easier with  `props.match.params` as the url is parsed

Comment: `withRouter` wraps your component with a pathless Route, and `match` job is to refer to the nearest ancestor route exist, what gonna be always itself with `withROuter` and therefore always `/`

Answer (score 0):

i tried different ways to handling header components

I decided to create reusable Header component and import it to all pages. Like that:

```js
const About = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header title="test" />
      <div>About</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

```js
const Users = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header title="users" rightCorner={<Notifications />} />
      <div>Users</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

It may help to customize Header for each page and you will have the access to the correct location and params inside Header